# Typescript: abstract/extract part of class functionality without using extends

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have a class that different areas of functionality:

```
export class TreeTable extends someOtherClass {
    constructor(){
       super.constructor();
    }
   //========= area 1 of functionality ====
   itemRightClick(){this.contextMenu();}
   contextMenu(){
     // open file or folder context menu
   }
   fileContextMenu(){}
   folderContextMenu(){}

   //========= area 2 of functionality ====
   loadData(){}
   subScribeStuff(){}
   unsusbscribeStuff(){}

   //======== area 3 SomeOtherClasses functionality
   someOtherClassMethod_1(){
   this.someOtherClassMethod();
   super.someOtherClassMethodTwo();
  }
}
```

And I want to extract abstract area-1 into an outer class.

```
class ContextMenu {
   constructor(){}
    //========= area 1 of functionality ====
   itemRightClick(){this.contextMenu();}
   contextMenu(){
     // open file or folder context menu
   }
   fileContextMenu(){}
   folderContextMenu(){}
}
export class TreeTable extends someOtherClass {

    constructor(){
       super.constructor();
    }
   //======== AREA 1
   // DECORATE THIS CLASS WITH class ContextMenu AND ADD ITS METHODS
   //========= area 2 of functionality ====
   loadData(){}
   subScribeStuff(){}
   unsusbscribeStuff(){}

   //======== area 3 SomeOtherClasses functionality
   someOtherClassMethod_1(){
   this.someOtherClassMethod();
   super.someOtherClassMethodTwo();
  }
}
```

looks like something that should be simple to be achieved.
Not looking for inheritance but decorating.
I saw that decorators (@) are not used for this porpuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, one important thing to note is that unlike strictly OOP languages, JS does not support abstract classes.

However, with your current class hierarchy it won't be possible to pick whatever memebers you want from a class X and give it to class Y without extending the whole X class.

Taking OOP and SOLID paradigms into account, you'd need to consider modelling your objects a little differently. 
Given these different "areas" of functionality, your class is becoming responsible for a lot of different responsibilities (loading data, subscribing and unsubscribing, and doing things with context menus) which can be separated either concretely in their own class definitions or abstractly by composing TypeScript interfaces.

Focusing specifically on the areas of functionality, 1-3, some options you have are:

**1. Isolate each area of related functionality and move those groups to their own classes**

```
class Area1 {
  ...
}

class Area2 {
  ...
}

class Area3 {
  ...
}
```

You can add instances of Area1, Area2, or Area3 as members of TreeTable or create a type hierarchy:

**2. Use TypeScript interfaces to express your classes members**

```
interface IArea1 {
  ...
}

interface IArea2 {
  ...
}

interface IArea3 {
  ...
}
```

then you can pick and choose what structure your concrete type should have by implementing as many interfaces are you like:

```
export class TreeTable extends someOtherClass implements IArea1, IArea3 {
  // implement members for IArea1
  // implement members for IArea2
}

Or construct an ITreeTable interface from other interfaces: 
interface ITreeTable extends IArea1, IArea3 {
  // any other functionality specific to ITreeTable
}

Then you class definition changes accordingly:
export class TreeTable extends someOtherClass implements ITreeTable {
  // implement members for IArea1
  // implement members for IArea2
}
```

**3. Forego OOP and use regular JavaScript objects; however, this is a bit of a drastic change if your code-base is largely object-oriented, plus consumer of your API will need to change too**

```
const area1 = {
  // some functions
}

const area2 = {
  // some other functions
}

const area3 = {
  // more functions
}

const treeTable = {
  ...area1,
  ...area3
}
```

You can still use the abstract interfaces here:

```
interface ITreeTable extends IArea1, IArea3 {
  // any other functionality specific to ITreeTable
}

const treeTable: ITreeTable = {
  // add all the necessary interface members
};
```

Comment: Thanks decided to go with the natural type of inheritance